# Why I get "Illegal Character Syntax Error Unterminated String Literal" when I using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

I have an error syntag when i using javascript.
This is my code

```
<a href=href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"poptastic ('ruang_utama.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>') type="button" heigh="10" width="10"> FORM RUANG </a></td>
```

and the error said "illegal character syntax error unterminated string literal"
Help me please!!!
I'm very confused how to handle it...

Answer (score 3):

You have few mistakes like `href=href=` then few issues with `"` as well

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="poptastic('ruang_utama.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>')"> FORM RUANG </a></td>
```

Comment: thank you, I think I was very tired so did not pay attention to this error

Comment: And assigning a type, width, and "heigh" to a link. And the space between `poptastic` and it's arguments.  OP- We've all been there. Get some rest.